# java2python only for 64-bit OS? j2py.exe says its incompatible for 64-bit OS when run from command line

Tags: java, python

I want to use java2python to be able to get a good head start converting a bunch of files over to python. The first thing I did to install was installed antlr 3.1.3 as prescribed. Then I installed java2python 0.5.0. Everything went well during this step:

```
C:\Users\Patrick>pip install java2python
Downloading/unpacking java2python
  Running setup.py (path:c:\users\patrick\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Patrick\j
ava2python\setup.py) egg_info for package java2python

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): antlr-python-runtime==
3.1.3 in c:\users\patrick\anaconda\lib\site-packages\antlr_python_runtime-3.1.3-
py2.7.egg (from java2python)
Installing collected packages: java2python
  Running setup.py install for java2python

Successfully installed java2python
Cleaning up..
```

However, when I try to use the command:

```
C:\Users\Patrick\Dekstop\Test\j2py DataWriter.java
```

I get the following error:

```
The program or feature "\??\C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\Scripts\j2py.exe" cannot start or run due to incompatibility with 64-bit versions of Windows. Please contact the software vendor to ask if a 64-bit Windows compatible version is available.
```

At this link it seems like there is some kind of download for windows 64-bit but it required ActivePython..? Anyways, if anyone has been able to get this work or knows another tool I can use to do the same thing please let me know. I am using Python 2.7.6 and my system is in fact 64-bit Windows 7.

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa384249%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)...

Comment: @AlexR "WOW64 is provided with the operating system and does not have to be explicitly enabled". So why am I getting this error then?

Comment: My guess is that it tries to load a win32 dll. If you have Windows >= 7 >= Professional, you can use virtualisation to execute it under a 32bit VM.

Comment: Yes your comment is basically what needs to be done. What I ended up doing is downloaded a Linux .iso which was actually 64-bit, ran it in a VM, got java2python installed on the native python installation and everything worked out. I guess the module is not really made for windows 64-bit specifically (as are many others I've found).

Comment: If you can post some steps to do what you mentioned (including downloading and somehow installing a 32-bit version of windows) then I can mark it as an answer.

Comment: I have posted an answer containing both approaches known to me with a remark regarding your findings concerning x64 linux distros. If you name the specific x64 distribution with wich you got it too run, I can add this detail as well.

Comment: OK great, I hope this saves some people time in the future. I used Ubuntu 14.04LTS 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Virtualisation feature of Windows 7 Professional (or Ultimate) or Windows 8 (Pro or Ultimate), you can use the [Windows XP mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/install-and-use-windows-xp-mode-in-windows-7) to run programs virtualised under 32 bit Windows XP.

Another option is to use a virtualisation software like VirtualBox and install a 32bit OS of your choice and use it to execute the software. (Strong PC recommended). As you mentioned, linux can even run java2python in a native 64-bit environment. (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit was confirmed to work)